# ASP Web Form - Stored Procedure Connection Was Not Closed

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use a stored procedure name P_AddAccount in my asp web page, and I keep getting the following error when filling out my form.

**The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.**

I've never tried c# until I had to make this, so sorry if I made an obvious mistake. Can someone please assist me?

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegDNMembershipConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.P_AddAccount");
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nvcAccountName", TextBoxUN.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyAccountLevelCode", 100));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("inyCharacterCreateLimit", "4"));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyCharacterMaxCount", 4));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt2LastLoginDate", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vchLastLoginIP", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@@IntLastSessionID", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vchJoinIP", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyPublisherCode", 4));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyGenderCode", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DaTBirthDate", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vchPassphrase", TextBoxPass.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyNationalityCode", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyChannelPartnerCode", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem));
        con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        Response.Write("<b>Something Really Bad Happened... Please Try Again.< /br></b>");
        Response.Write(er.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Any Special Action You Want To Add....
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You're opening your connection twice look at your code...

Comment: Ahhh okay, I removed the `con.Open();` before `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` but now I get this error. 

**ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.**

Comment: Take a look at my answer below (I have posted this a few minutes ago)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opened the same connection twice - you should open it once in the beginning and then close it at the end.

But then this will anyway probably not work as there is no relation between the SqlConnection and SqlCommand instances. You should assign your instance of SqlConnection to the instance of Command class:

```
command.Connection = con;
```

So after the above changes your code should look like this:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegDNMembershipConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("dbo.P_AddAccount");
        command.Connection = con; 
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nvcAccountName", TextBoxUN.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyAccountLevelCode", 100));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("inyCharacterCreateLimit", "4"));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyCharacterMaxCount", 4));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dt2LastLoginDate", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vchLastLoginIP", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@@IntLastSessionID", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vchJoinIP", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyPublisherCode", 4));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyGenderCode", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DaTBirthDate", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@vchPassphrase", TextBoxPass.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyNationalityCode", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@inyChannelPartnerCode", null));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmailAddress", TextBoxEA.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FullName", TextBoxFN.Text));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        Response.Write("<b>Something Really Bad Happened... Please Try Again.< /br></b>");
        Response.Write(er.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        //Any Special Action You Want To Add....
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. I've never worked with this stuff before, and I'm having a hard time understanding. Can you please explain a bit more or show me an example? Thanks for your reply, Bejger!